# How to list all apps in cloudfoundry using python

Tags: python, cloud-foundry

I am trying access my `CloudFoundry` apps in python and i am using `requests` module.
First I have tried

```
import requests
response=requests.get("https://api.run.pivotal.io")
```

It is showing UnAuthorized error. for my knowledge First we have to get the token from authentication server. so I have used

```
response=requests.get('https://login.run.pivotal.io',auth=('username','pwd'))
```

It is successfull and getting response code 200. my doubt is how to get my apps data. I am trying

```
response=requests.get("https://api.run.pivotal.io/v2/apps",'Authorization':'access_token myToken')
```

but still getting UnAuthorized error. How to give `access token` in headers, because login url is different so that i am not able to access that.

Comment: Read the documentation. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers

Comment: I know how to use requests, but the thing is i have to get `access_token` from one url and data from another url. To get data I have to give `access_token` to second url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests
oauthTokenResponse = requests.post(
    'https://login.run.pivotal.io/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=cf', 
    data={'username': 'YOUR_USERNAME', 'password': 'YOUR_PASSWORD', 'client_id': 'cf'},
    auth=('cf', '')
)
authorization = oauthTokenResponse.json()['token_type'] + ' ' + oauthTokenResponse.json()['access_token']
appsResponse = requests.get(
    "https://api.run.pivotal.io/v2/apps",
    headers={'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': authorization}
)
```

Comment: It's perfectly working, and I have another doubt using requests only I am trying to upload bits `appsResponse = requests.put(
    "https://api.run.pivotal.io/v2/apps/914e28c6-d987-4917-97fd-55185688c314/bits",
    headers={'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/zip', 'Authorization': authorization},
    data={'application':'application.zip'}
)`
But it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something else, you will need a CLI for this script
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli

```
from __future__ import print_function
import subprocess
import os
import re
import getpass

User = raw_input("Please Enter your user name: \n").lower()
if not re.match("^[a-zA-Z, 0-99]*$", User):
    print ("Error! Only letters and numbers are allowed!")
    break
Pass = getpass.getpass(prompt= "Please enter your password: \n")


URL_login = 'cf login --skip-ssl-validation -a https://api.run.pivotal.io -u ' + User.lower() + ' -p ' + Pass
subprocess.call(URL_login)
os.system('cf apps > apps.csv')
```